# Ansible: how to run a command as user that no shell

Tags: ansible

I have to run a symfony clear cache on several hosts as the user *apache* which has **/sbin/nologin** as shell in /etc/passwd. usually I do this with the following command: `sudo su - apache -s /bin/bash -c "php /var/www/html/api/bin/console cache:clear --env=prod"`

Currently my playbook looks like this:

```
    ---
    - name: "test"
    hosts: app-servers
    gather_facts: yes
    become: yes
    tasks:
      - name: "Clear symfony cache"
        command: sudo su - apache -s /bin/bash -c "php /var/www/html/api/bin/console cache:clear --env=prod"
```

But during the run I receive a warning:

```
[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo
```

I tried several combination but I was never able to get it work.

I'm an ansible noobie and I would like to understand the best way to run this task using ansible.

Comment: That warning will occur any time  you use sudo via the command or shell module.  It's informational only, and does not affect the attempted command execution

Comment: I understand, but that warning makes me think I don't use the right way to perform the task

Comment: using `become: yes` and `sudo` is redundant.  I would try remove the `sudo` part of the command, and test that.

Comment: it runs but now I get a warning : `[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running su`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
---
- name: "test"
hosts: app-servers
gather_facts: yes
become: yes
become_user: apache
become_flags: '-s /bin/bash'
tasks:
  - name: "Clear symfony cache"
    command: "php /var/www/html/api.sellsecure.com/bin/console cache:clear --env=prod"
```